# How to select previous record not depends on ID which is AutoIncrements in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii

Say, I have table named `tbl_order` on MySQL with structure like this (just illustration):

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id | grade | type  | order_date          | order_confim_time   | vol_in | vol_out | vol_dev | status  |
| AI | VARCH | VARCH | TIMESTAMP           | TIMESTAMP           | DOUBLE | DOUBLE  | DOUBLE  | VARCH   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 81 | AAA   | IN    | 2014-09-10 09:00:00 | 2014-09-10 13:00:00 | 498000 |       0 |   -2000 | CONFIRM |
| 83 | AAA   | IN    | 2014-09-10 10:01:00 | 2014-09-10 14:00:00 | 998000 |       0 |   -2000 | CONFIRM |
| 85 | AAA   | OUT   | 2014-09-11 09:02:00 | 2014-09-11 13:00:00 |      0 |   99000 |   -1000 | CONFIRM |
| 87 | AAA   | OUT   | 2014-09-11 10:03:00 | 2014-09-11 14:00:00 |      0 |  145000 |   -5000 | CONFIRM |
| 89 | AAA   | OUT   | 2014-09-12 09:04:00 | 2014-09-12 13:00:00 |      0 |  120000 |   -5000 | CONFIRM |
| 91 | AAA   | OUT   | 2014-09-12 09:06:00 | NULL                |      0 |  130000 |   -2000 | NOTCONF |
| 93 | AAA   | OUT   | 2014-09-13 10:05:00 | 2014-09-12 14:00:00 |      0 |  115000 |   -5000 | CONFIRM |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Then I did the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_order` WHERE `tbl_order`.`grade` = 'AAA' AND `tbl_order`.`order_confim_time` < NOW() ORDER BY `tbl_order`.`status` DESC, `tbl_order`.`order_confim_time` ASC
```

So that in we could get following result:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id | grade | type  | order_date          | order_confim_time   | vol_in | vol_out | vol_dev | status  |
| AI | VARCH | VARCH | TIMESTAMP           | TIMESTAMP           | DOUBLE | DOUBLE  | DOUBLE  | VARCH   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 91 | AAA   | OUT   | 2014-09-12 09:06:00 | NULL                |      0 |  130000 |   -2000 | NOTCONF |
| 93 | AAA   | OUT   | 2014-09-13 10:05:00 | 2014-09-12 14:00:00 |      0 |  115000 |   -5000 | CONFIRM |
| 89 | AAA   | OUT   | 2014-09-12 09:04:00 | 2014-09-12 13:00:00 |      0 |  120000 |   -5000 | CONFIRM |
| 87 | AAA   | OUT   | 2014-09-11 10:03:00 | 2014-09-11 14:00:00 |      0 |  145000 |   -5000 | CONFIRM |
| 85 | AAA   | OUT   | 2014-09-11 09:02:00 | 2014-09-11 13:00:00 |      0 |   99000 |   -1000 | CONFIRM |
| 83 | AAA   | IN    | 2014-09-10 10:01:00 | 2014-09-10 14:00:00 | 998000 |       0 |   -2000 | CONFIRM |
| 81 | AAA   | IN    | 2014-09-10 09:00:00 | 2014-09-10 13:00:00 | 498000 |       0 |   -2000 | CONFIRM |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I did write following function in my model `Order` in order to get previous row using recursive:

```
    // i made simplify code, but still the code only work on 1st previous row. the rest still not.
    public function getPrevRow() {
    if (is_null($this->order_confim_time))
        {
            $data = self::model()->find(array(
                'condition' => '`t`.`grade`=:type_order AND (`t`.`order_date` '`t`.`status` DESC, `t`.`order_confim_time` DESC, `t`.`id` DESC',
                'limit'     => 1,
                'params'    => array('type_order' => $this->grade, ':current_date_confirm' => $this->order_confim_time),
            ));

            if (is_null($data)) return 0;
            else return floatval($data->PrevRow) +
            floatval($data->vol_in) +
            floatval($data->vol_dev) -
            floatval($data->vol_out);
        } else {
            $data = self::model()->find(array(
                'condition' => '`t`.`order_confim_time` '`t`.`status` DESC, `t`.`id` DESC',
                'limit'     => 1,
                'params'    => array(':current_date_confirm' => $this->order_confim_time, 'type_order' => $this->grade),
            ));

            if (is_null($data)) return 0;
            else return floatval($data->PrevRow) +
            floatval($data->vol_in) +
            floatval($data->vol_dev) -
            floatval($data->vol_out);
        }
    }
```

The result quite good and only respects `order_confirm_time` with `NOT NULL` values.

[Current result in CGridView](http://imgbox.com/SKf73tAy)

[The expected condition is something like this](http://imgbox.com/ocnyOCha)

How can I get previous row without need to depends on `ORDER BY id DESC`? Currently I depends on `ORDER BY order_confirm_time`.

I am using YII 1.1.16-branch, php 5.4 @ Windows 7 x64, MariaDB 5.5.38

Comment: I don't understand your question "How can I get row with id = 93 without need to depends on ORDER BY id DESC", can you just post the output you're trying to get?

Comment: @brian-demilia, sorry if my question is unclear. The goal / expected result is I could get previous row id without depends on `id` field. Currently i am using `ORDER BY order_confim_time` but only display not null (order_confim_time with values) data.

Please take a look on this pic [current condition](http://imgbox.com/SKf73tAy). There are 2 circles, red and green. I want to make something like this [expected condition](http://imgbox.com/ocnyOCha).

Comment: @Brian DeMilia, any ideas on my case? I already simplify my code but still, only get first previous row. the rest still pointed to first previous row.

Answer (score 0):

In pseudo code, you can do like this:

1. initialize tempv_var
2. initialize my_array
3. loop your records
4. do some conditions here before passing records to your my_array
5. stored records in my_array[temp_var]
6. increment temp_var

At the end you have your my_array that contents records with an index of temp_var.  This is the straight forward solutions, but you can do this within your SQL query and adding some logic on your script.